# Render CustomElements dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I wrote a helper to set up all CustomElements dynamically:

```
let moduleDefaults = new Map();
let customElementsMap = new Map();

const registerComponents = () => {
    // ^ Check for .ce files -> then register components
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filePaths)) {
        if (value.name.toLowerCase().includes(".ce.vue")) {
            let name = value.name.split(/[\\\/]/).pop().toLowerCase();

            value().then(module => {
                moduleDefaults.set(name.substr(0, name.indexOf('.')), module.default);
            })
        }
    }
}

registerComponents();

PK_CE.pkShowCustomModal = async (tagName = "", url = "", params = {}) => {
    let props = {};
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(url, {
            params: params,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            }
        });

        props = cloneDeep(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    var existing = document.getElementsByTagName("custom-" + tagName),
        tag = document.createElement("custom-" + tagName);

    // ^ IF - If element is not mounted yet -> append element to DOM and set attribute
    // ^ ELSE - To Mount element after closing delete html tag and create new element with new data
    if (!existing.length) {
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        existing[0].setAttribute("data", JSON.stringify(props));
    } else if (existing && existing[0].hasAttribute("data")) {
        document.body.removeChild(existing[0]);
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        existing[0].setAttribute("data", JSON.stringify(props));
    }

    // TODO Element shows before custom element is defined after getting re-created!!!! WHY THOO?!
    if (moduleDefaults.size > 0) {
        try {
            if (!customElementsMap.has(tagName)) {
                customElementsMap.set(tagName, defineCustomElement(moduleDefaults.get(tagName)));
            }

            if (!customElements.get("custom-" + tagName)) window.customElements.define("custom-" + tagName, customElementsMap.get(tagName));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("ERROR:", error);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

registerComponents: Search the files for ".ce.vue" files to register the custom component root files.

pkShowCustomModal: Creates the html DOM elements by their tag name and defines the custom Elements. If already existing -> removes the html Element from the DOM and creates a new one to re-register the custom elements. Otherwise the CustomElements won't show again (e.g. Modals).

Problem: The first mount works perfectly. But on removoving and re-creating the elements the Components tries to render BEFORE `window.customElements.define("custom-" + tagName, customElementsMap.get(tagName));` is even called. Hence the `props` are undefined.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. The problem was the order of assigning the `data` attribute to the element. I just had to switch these elements like:

```
existing[0].setAttribute("data", JSON.stringify(props));
document.body.appendChild(tag);
```